# Can I setup W7 to work in my new System?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive

I've changed basically my whole computer but the system drive, in the new one I have another drive with Windows installed so now my older one is the F: disk instead the system one, so, in this scenario, **There is a way to "repair" the original W7 installation to work with the new motherboard *FROM* the current(in other drive) windows installation?**

Comment: In theory, running setup, then choosing upgrade from previous install should correct it, but there are no guarantees here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you: Maybe.

- There is the method LPchip mentioned, which may work.
- Or you could put the old disk back int he old computer, uninstall as many drivers as possible and run `sysprep`, and then yty to boot it in the new computer. (The process is described in several other posts here on [su]).

But I got the feeling that the question you asked is not the question which you want answered. Thus, **why** do you want the old windows install on the new computer?

Is it to get a different version (e.g. old one was win7 ultimate and the current one is win7 basic) ?
Is it to transfer old programs or old setting?

Esp the last might get quite different answers than to move a while windows installation over. (Which might not even be legal if the old install was OEM'ed).

Comment: The reason is that my old MB broke and i need a new one, and also update CPU etc... and I don't want to reinstall everythig

Comment: Stability wise: Reinstalling everything is probably the best bet. Skipping that you could just try to boot of the old disk. Which may work. Or is the new motherboard is different enough it may not boot succesfully at all. Removing the new HDD and trying to boot is easy enough to test though. Also, BIOS or UEFI? (both for the old installl and the new one).